# Обьединить два DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder в один

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Можно ли, используя Java API, совместить два запроса на удаление? 
Пробую сделать так:

```
DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder(client.getClient(), DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(matchQuery("leftId", leftId())).must(matchQuery("rightId", rightId())))
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(matchQuery("leftId", rightId())).must(matchQuery("rightId", leftId())));

requestBuilder.get();
```

Но выполняется только один запрос - последний запрос.

Comment: Используйте bulk request

Comment: пример можете показать пожалуйста?

Comment: Так, я оригинальный запрос не сразу разглядел, здесь даже bulk не нужен. Вам достаточно обернуть оба запроса в bool query с should. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552321/or-and-and-operators-in-elasticsearch-query

Comment: мне  bool query с should не подходит, так как: в первом запросе мне нужно удалить индекс, где leftId = "left',  rightId = "right", а во втором запросе они меняются местами leftId = "right',  rightId = "left" (эти два индекса - пара). но, может быть индекс с leftId = "left', который имеет другую пару или не имеет её вообще и его удалять не нужно.

Comment: should - это немного усложненный "ИЛИ", сделайте "(leftId = right И rightId = left) ИЛИ (leftId = left И rightId = right)" - `should(must(leftId = right, rightId = left), must(leftId = left, rightId = right))`

Comment: should принимает только один QueryBuilder и я не могу передеть в него два must

Comment: он вызывается несколько раз, ну https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/3a82c613e43ebfaa010e5cf5e79cc54cee2d9468/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/BoolQueryBuilder.java#L173-L179

Comment: идеально! спасибо Вам огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Нет нельзя, в билдере один запрос перетирается на другой, из за этого и выполняется последний.